# Unable to make JMX connection remotely when application running under docker

Tags: docker, jmx

I have application running within jetty container. I have initialized the JMX process under jetty container. These all processes are running under docker container.
When i try to make remote connection using JCONSOLE to connect my JMX host:port i am unable to connect.

My physical host machine : **matrix01lx** (This is where docker container is running)
My docker virtual IP address : **172.17.0.2**.

Now when i want to connect using JMX i am able to connect, only when i do connection from the physical host where docker container is running i.e. matrix01lx in my case.

I connect using :  `service:jmx:rmi://host/jndi/rmi://matrix01lx:11041/smp.serverruntime`

Remote connection fails when connecting through JCONSOLE saying,

```
 java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: **172.17.0.2**; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at com.sigma.jmxClient.Connect.main(Connect.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 8 more
```

I have refer to forums and tried setting following properties in my MAVEN_OPTS when starting mvn process and explicitly in code as well.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=11041
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=matrix01lx (also tried putting IP address here)
```

**Note** : I have tried disabling firewall. I am using centOS 7

Please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration is known to work for a Java application running in a container.

java.rmi.server.hostname should be the same hostname you're connecting with.
Make sure it's resolvable from the originating machine.

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=matrix01lx
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access`

See a working example for ActiveMQ in container:

https://github.com/axibase/atsd/tree/master/integration/activemq

Comment: java.rmi.server.hostname=matrix01lx is resolvable and it's IP address is say 10.11.10.22, and if you see in log when we connect using **matrix01lx**  ,this tries to connect docker contianer host Ip as shown in logs above. And that host not resolved i think so it is failing.

Comment: Why is JCONSOLE trying to connect to **172.17.0.2**? 
java.rmi.server.hostname=matrix01lx, jmxremote.port and jmxremote.rmi.port are set to 11041 and matrix01lx resolves to 10.11.10.22 on the jconsole machine, correct? No domain names are involved?

Comment: Yes correct but  What it tries to do is, as matrix01lx has docker container running where it has published port 11041 of JMX and it know the host of docker i.e. 172.17.0.2, so ultimately from remote someone tries to connect JMX at end it gets the docker IP address. Don't know why this happening. And even if it gets docker IP , 172.17.0.2 is already resolved by matrix01lx rigth,?
Something weird happening.

Comment: Do you have all 5 settings set as displayed above, other than access/password files?

Comment: I have all the setting except, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1090 as  my code do create this and set

Comment: This needs to be set:  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11041

Comment: If i do so, i get Error: Object ID Already in use.. since i told this is alreday being created.

Comment: No idea what Error: Object ID means. I know that both jmxremote.port and jmxremote.rmi.port are required for this to work. If you can't have it set, there is something wrong.

Comment: I will try this to set in my code explicitly now and get you the exact error in few mins.I have not tried above property setting in code, but i did set in my MAVEN_OPTS. let me check.

Comment: I am not produce the error, something might have messed earlier, now i have all properties set you suggested in my code and in my MAVEN_OPTS as well. Still no luck. returning same error. Do i need to expose the docker host somehow?

Comment: Once you have those JMX settings in place, I would start by checking that the container is actually listening on 11041 and that the docker host is listening on the same port 11041. This port needs to be exposed (published) when container is started.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111865/discussion-between-sohan-and-sergei-rodionov).

Comment: Above accepted answer is the solution. I had some typos in properties that were set. And of course port were published to make it accessible outside container.